# Is it possible to play audio on local computer from a flask app in Google Cloud Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

**I am trying to create an website where users can input text, and the text will be read out on my local machine**.

To achieve this, I have used a simple Flask app with Google cloud text to speech, and am deploying it through Google App Engine.
The app is functional, and no errors appear in the app engine error log, however the **audio will not play**.

I am wondering how to send audio from the app to be played by my local computer. Is it possible? Or do I need to use a completely different method? I'm very new to all these tools.

Here is my main.py:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request
    from gtts import gTTS
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    import os
    import tempfile
    from playsound import playsound

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route("/")
    def homepage():
        return render_template("page.html", title="HOME PAGE")

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == "POST":
            text = request.form['text']

            os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="credentials.json"

            client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
            input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)
            voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
                language_code='en-US',
                name='en-US-Standard-C',
                ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

            audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
                audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

            response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)

            # The response's audio_content is binary.
            with open('/tmp/output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
                out.write(response.audio_content)
                os.system("start output.mp3")
            thankyou = "thanks"
            return thankyou

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Talk to Wednesday</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Talk to Me </h1>
    <form method="POST">
      <input name="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.yml simply has: "runtime: python37"

Requirements.txt:

```
   Flask==1.1.2
   pyttsx3
   gtts
   google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
   gunicorn==20.0.4; python_version > '3.0'
   backports.tempfile
   playsound
```

Comment: Can you get it to work locally on your computer? Take GAE out of the picture to narrow down the issues.

Comment: @gaefan I've added code to my answer that should work (tested in Firefox). I guess you can just return file that should autoplay in browser. This work without GAE and you can run it locally.

Comment: Hi, it runs perfectly locally. I've also been using ngrok, which works fine, but would prefer to use GAE as it's more secure long-term.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is:

A) You have to save MP3 files into Google Cloud Storage. So after you generate file, save it in GCS bucket and make it accessible via URL.

B) Return HTML page with

```
<audio autoplay controls="controls">

   <source src="{your_gcs_url_to_mp3_file}" />

</audio>
```

If you have any more questions let me know, and I will try help with more details.

PS. You could of course directly return MP3 file for download, but I think it isn't what You are asking for.

**EDIT**

To improve my answer refer to code below. This show how to automatically get back MP3 file that should autoplay in browser ( tested in Firefox ).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request
from google.cloud import texttospeech
from io import BytesIO
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template("page.html", title="HOME PAGE")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form['text']

        client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
        input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)
        voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
            language_code='en-US',
            name='en-US-Standard-C',
            ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

        audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
            audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

        response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)
        file = BytesIO()
        file.write(response.audio_content)
        file.seek(0)
        return send_file(file, mimetype="audio/mpeg")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi @galuszkak, thanks for this code. A question: will users who enter text have the audio played from their browser, or from my computer? I am trying to get all audio playing from my local computer only.

Comment: @hugkes it will play from their browser. 
So question:
A) This has to be deployed in GAE
B) After someone will write something on website in GAE you want this to be played on your local computer.

Is this what you want to achieve? If yes then:

Basically to achieve that you need 2 processes, not one. One is deployed app in GAE, but you need something on your local laptop to receive generated mp3 file and play it.

One way to achieve that would be save all MP3 files in GCS bucket, and scan GCS bucket from local computer for new files, play them and after playing delete those.

Comment: Yep B) is what I was going for.  I think I will stick to the ngrok solution for now - much simpler! Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder inside static folder of your project and put the audio file inside it, and use audio tag in html to play the audio file by giving path of the audio file using src attribute of audio tag. It will surely work.

Comment: Actually I don't think there is any need for doing that, I myself two days back was facing the same issue, and I was looking for alternatives, and one of the alternatives I thought was same as @hugkes, so that's why I suggested the solution which I found after long hours of searching on the internet. I think this is the answer which hugkes is looking for.